# In Cakephp, can I use afterSave() in the model to perform additional tasks depending on what was just saved?

Tags: cakephp

I have two models: Drawing has many Panels and Panels belongs to Drawing. Every time a panel is saved, I'd like to check if it's the third panel to be added to a Drawing. If it is, I'd like to merge the three panels into one new png file and save the png's filename and path to the Drawing table.

```
class Drawing extends AppModel {
  public $name = 'Drawing';
  public $hasMany = array(
    'Panel' => array(
        'className' => 'Panel',
        'dependent' => true,
        'fields' => array('id', 'filepath', 'filename', 'placement')
        )
  );
}

class Panel extends AppModel {
  public $name = 'Panel';
  public $belongsTo = array(
    'Drawing'=>array(
        'className'=>'Drawing',
        'foreignKey'=>'drawing_id',
        'counterCache' => true
        )
    );
}
```

Since I set counterCache to true in the Panel model, I keep track of the panels with panel_count in my drawings table -- and I can check when there are 3 panels. I think the best way would be to use an afterSave() callback. That way, I can check if there are now three panels and if there are I can update whatever I want. (My controller prevents user from adding new panels once there are three). However, I don't think that the code below works -- it stops other parts of my app from functioning and if I remove the afterSave() function, everything works again. How can I check panel_count from within my Drawing model? Is there a better way to do this?

```
// Inside of the Drawing model... 
public function afterSave($created){
  if ($this->data[panel_count] == 3){
    // create a new image by merging the three panel images together
    // add the filename and path of the new image to the database
  }
}
```

Comment: have you had a look at the error logs?

Comment: It's not an expensive check to make, so running it in `afterSave` is justifiable to me. I'd be adding the line: `parent::afterSave($created);` so that afterSaves up the inheritance chain are still going to run. This may be breaking your app. Also, it's easy to create infinite loops in afterSaves - your error may be PHP reaching it's recursion limit.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new model method to do the functionality and save with that method from the controller. The reason for this is the change in the Drawing.panel_count property (you have to update the Drawing record and this creates an afterSave loop).

I usually avoid callbacks for any data mangling (especially within the same model), since they run every time and sometimes I just simply want to SAVE without the extra mangling. It is also much easier to move a piece of code from a method to an afterSave callback later than the other way around.